# How to convert the var in js into java?

Tags: java, javascript, numbers

Now I'm try to convert some js code into java , there is a problem:

In js

> 46022*65535 = 3016051770
>
> and
>
> (46022*65535)|7867 = -1278910789

In java

> 46022*65535 = -1278915526 this is overflow
>
> 46022L*65535L = 3016051770L this is the same result to js
>
> (46022*65535)|7867 = -1278910789 this one and the one below is the problem
>
> (46022L*65535L)|7867L = 3016056507L

So , **why the `|` operator will make two positive number to be nagtive number?**
What's the different between java and js when dealing with the int and long to do this operation?

And then , how to write java code compatible with js in this situation ?

**Attention:I know the range of int and long , my problem is `|`.**

More problems :

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators
`&` is also 32bit operation, then:
In js

> 2996101485 & 65535 = 57709

In java

> 2996101485 is overflow to int so I use double to store it and cast it into int when I need to do AND.
>
> double a = 2996101485l;
>
> double b = 65535;
>
> int c  = (int) a & (int) b; Now c = 65535

But if I use long to cast :

> long c  = (long) a & (long) b; Now c = 57709

So , just simply cast double into int will cause problems. And I want to know why?

I got the problem , 2996101485 can be present in 32bit in js and in java it should be long. So I write functions to convert those operations , for example, `&` should use this java function to run give same result in js:

```
private double doOR(double x, double y) {
    if (x > Integer.MAX_VALUE && x <= 1l << 32) {
        if (y > Integer.MAX_VALUE && y <= 1l << 32) {
            return (long) x | (long) y;
        } else {
            return (long) x | (int) y;
        }
    } else {
        return (int) x | (int) y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm nominating for a reopen.  The one that marked as a duplicate may explain `|`, but it's not the *same* question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while numbers in JavaScript [have roughly 53-bit precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) (they appear to be based on floating point doubles), the [bitwise OR operates on only 32 bits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

> Bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeroes and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers.

This means that when working with arithmetic, `long` will get you the JavaScript-like arithmetic (with numbers such as yours), since Java `int`s will overflow; but when working with bitwise operations, `int` will get you the JavaScript-like results, since then both platforms are operating on 32-bit numbers.

Comment: So when I use OR operates , js let the number be 32bit precision?

Comment: Essentially, yes. At least, what's what it appears from what I've read! I don't know JavaScript as well as I know Java.

Comment: I see your update, if I just cast `long` into `int` before I do the OR operates , will it run like js?

Comment: That should work, yes -- but make sure to cast _all_ of the operands to `int`, or else just a single one will cause them all to get promoted to `long`!

Comment: btw, that's just what you had in your third Java snippet, `(46022*65535)|7867 = -1278910789` -- in that snippet, all the operands are `int`.

Comment: Yes , I will be careful ,there  just one line has this problem. :-)

Comment: I have found more problems relate to the cast ,could you point the problem out?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `long` instead.

```
System.out.println(46022L*65535L); // = 3016051770
```

Java has ints and longs.

```
    System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);  // = 2147483647
    System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);  // = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

As for the language difference, I can only attribute it to different precisions between the languages.  [If you see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin), you'll see the largest number in JS is 9,007,199,254,740,992.  That's a guess, it might be for another reason.

Comment: I have tried this , but the result is different from js when using `|` .